# How can I make a demand command loop?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a command named demand and need to make a limit to amounts per user. There are roles in the server named "team_role" and then there's also "2 demands", "1 demand", and "0 demands". After the user demands, I need it to role them down a demand until eventually, they hit 0. Once they hit 0, it should send them a message saying they can't demand. Here's my code for one of the teams (the Dallas Cowboys).

```
@bot.command(aliases=["<:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592>"])
@commands.has_any_role("Dallas Cowboys")
async def t(ctx):
  guild = bot.get_guild(766292887914151949)
  role_name = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Free Agent')
  role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Dallas Cowboys')
  embed = discord.Embed()
  embed.add_field(name="<a:CheckMark:768095274949935146> Successful Demand", value=f"{ctx.author.mention} has demanded from the <:DallasCowboys:788796627161710592>")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  await ctx.author.add_roles(role_name)
  await ctx.author.remove_roles(role)
```

Comment: How long do you want this limit to last? Do you want them to only get 2 demands in their lifetime, or do you ever plan for the limit to reset? Is it worth storing this data so that if the bot is reinitialized that the amount of demands stay the same?

Comment: I want this time limit to last forever because, at the end of each season, I reset everyone's demands using double counter.

Comment: Okay cool. If not, I was going to simply suggest a dictionary, but if you want to store state, you'll need to either store this data in a json file or database. Do you need help with that part, or do you just want me to provide the logic in my answer?

Comment: You can provide the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said I can just provide the logic:

1. Create a means of persistently storing the data, whether that be
   json file or a database.

   a) If you choose the json file, the file will consist of key value
   pairs of user ids to number of demands remaining. For example, the
   file might look something like this:

   ```
   { "UserDemandsRemaining" : { 12345 : 2, 45678: 1, 09876: 0 } }
   ```

   b) If you choose to use to use a SQL database, create a table called
   `UserDemandsRemaining` with two fields: `UserId` and
   `DemandsRemaining`. The primary key would be `UserId`.
2. Each time a user makes a demand, you will check how many remaining
   demands the user has.

   #### If there is no matching UserId stored:

   a) If you chose to use a json file, and there is no matching key in the json value associated with the `UserDemandsRemaining` key, then create a key-value pair with the key as the `UserId` that made the demand, and the value as 3.

   b) If you chose to use a SQL db, and there is no matching `UserId` matching the `UserId` that made the demand in the `UserDemandsRemaining` table of the database, then insert a row into the table containing the `UserId` that made the demand and a `DemandsRemaining` value of 3.

   Since the user isn't stored, we know that they have not yet made any demands. Execute the demand. Then decrement the `DemandsRemaining` by 1.

   #### Else if there is a matching UserId:

   if `DemandsRemaining` > 0:

   ```
   #Execute the command. Decrement `DemandsRemaining` by 1.
   ```

   else:

   ```
   #Notify the user that they have no more remaining demands.
   ```
3. In order to reset the number of demands each person has remaining,
   just set the value pair  associated with the users in the json file
   or the `DemandsRemaining` in the table to 3 for everyone.

Comment: Sorry about not answering for a long while, but one thing that I forgot to mention in my question is that I use a website called https://repl.it/ that I code on. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @axlol Yes, I believe that you can do this with repl.it DB https://repl.it/talk/learn/Replit-DB/43305